# Responsive design images inside ul, which don't resize

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, html-lists

I have unordered list of images, in a responsive design. The images scale properly, when I resize window. But the trouble is wrapper UL element, which don't adjust its height accordance with image height. This create a big gab before following P element.

http://jsfiddle.net/6qrad/1/

How can I achieve height of `ul` element to adjust accordingly without floating `li`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all whenever you are going for responsive design, be sure you use the below snippet

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

If you are aware of the CSS box model, the above will do exact opposite of that, it will count the `padding`, `border` inside the element instead of `outside` the element.

Now coming to the solution, you are using `column-count` property which I think is not required in your case, you can simply use `float: left;` and than use `overflow: hidden;` to clear the floating `li`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/6qrad/2/)

Use [`font-size: 0;`](http://jsfiddle.net/6qrad/4/) if you want to get rid of the remaining pink portion at the bottom. (Using `width: 33.33%` to be precise, which will get rid of the pink color on the right hand side as well.)

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/6qrad/3/) (With gaps, used `padding`)

Also, as I was editing the question, you've mentioned you don't want to `float`, so I don't see any specific reason for not doing so, but still if you don't want to float, you can use `display: inline-block;` with a `width` set to `33%` each, also make sure you use `margin-left: -4px;` to deal with the `white-space` by making your `li` elements `inline-block`

Comment: Finally I gave up the idea of using column and worked out in traditional way of (Li) floating left. Yes i am aware of box-sizing, but yours using margin-left: -4px, for li inline-block is new to me. Also font-size: 0, is I would not use because I always work fontsize with em not px, so that will make more difficult calculating. Finally I think i'll do it as [Final Work](http://jsfiddle.net/REyd6/). HTML is from  CMS i am using.

Comment: @tenzin cool, you can use any approach whichever suits your needs :)